# Events are disabled within default "theme.res"

Tags: events, codenameone

I just created a Codename One project with netbeans.
This created me a file called "theme.res" in the "src\" folder.
When I open it with GUI Builder, events are disabled.
This is not clear to me what do I need to do to enable these events.

I took a copy of these "theme.res". The copy is also located in the "src\" folder. Events are neither enabled....

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you picked a handcoded application instead of a GUI builder application. When you create a new project you are given an option to generate either a GUI builder app (which will have events enabled) or a handcoded app which will need you to handcode event handling.

Comment: No, I started with the wizard where I picked a theme and a default structure (a tabs structure). This generated me little application. Where events are not enabled.

Comment: Did you refactor the source directories? Did you change anything about the project? What do you mean by "the copy is also located in the src"? theme.res is only in the src directory and you should only use that theme file.

Comment: Actually the original "theme.res" is fine. The problem I've got is with the copies I take from this file. Let's say "theme2.res". If I open this Res file, then the events are disabled.

Comment: Only one theme file can be used for events see http://www.codenameone.com/architecture-of-the-gui-builder.html Since events are mapped to a single source file this is a hardcoded assumption. You can use additional resource files for more resources (images, localizations, themes etc.) but if you add GUI elements you will need to map them manually using the UIBuilder class.